# Converting rows of data which contains a list into NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures

I have a dataframe like this:

```
 A      B      C
John    45    [1,0] 
Carl    3     [1,2,1]
Fred    4     [-1]
```

As seen above in column 'C' a few of the rows contain lists. My objective is to convert them to NaN values. I want the output to look like this:

```
   A      B      C
John     45     NaN 
Carl     3      NaN
Fred     4      [-1]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want replace lists with length higher as 1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) with boolean mask created by [`len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```
df.C = df.C.mask(df.C.str.len() > 1)
```

Or:

```
df.C = np.where(df.C.str.len() > 1, np.nan, df.C)
```

---

```
print (df)
      A   B     C
0  John  45   NaN
1  Carl   3   NaN
2  Fred   4  [-1]
```

If want convert one item lists to scalars:

```
df.C = np.where(df.C.str.len() == 1,  df.C.str[0], np.nan)
print (df)
      A   B    C
0  John  45  NaN
1  Carl   3  NaN
2  Fred   4 -1.0
```

Comment: Thanks! My next question was to remove the lists completely. My last question is what if there are values like this `[]` @jezrael

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
df['C'][df['C'].apply(len)>1] = np.nan
```

result:

```
      A     B    C
0   John    45  NaN
1   Carl    3   NaN
2   Fred    4   [-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `loc`

```
df.loc[df.C.str.len() > 1, "C"] = np.nan
```